# what is the prefix name in the uri driver

Tags: python, python-3.x, neo4j

I saw several examples of opening driver to work with neo4j (from `python`):

```
from neo4j import GraphDatabase
uri = "neo4j://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))
```

or

```
uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(uri, auth=("neo4j", "password"))
```

1. What are the `bolt` or `neo4j` before the `::/localhost:7687`?
2. Do I need to create them in advance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bolt` and `neo4j` are just URI [schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Definition) that are automatically understood by neo4j, without any effort on your part.